# Guest Links are not working all the time

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-online, links

I have been using sharepoint guest links for years now for my company. I have the links on our website that link to our product PDFs. I noticed a few weeks ago that when i create the guest links the format of the link producing algorithm has changed and creates a different link style/format.

It used to be something like this: https://ceramictechnics.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=03cc698f7675240be991a14c0f13b40c5&authkey=AeXctSlm3BvK_J-111g_oao

Now it is like this:
https://ceramictechnics.sharepoint.com/:b:/g/ER--dhKuM9pFsfKd5RmS_zoB1Ou1M8VgGGbur-xq34Dx-Q

Regardless, I have been getting wind of some issues that the links are broken or the website goes to an error page. I don't know why this issues is occurring, as i will check it on different devices on and off our network and they work fine.

For some of the guest links that are occasionally broken i have updated some documents (retaining existing file name) like I normally do and this was the most recent one i heard the link wasn't working on. This specific link was originally saved in the 'old' guest link format, but I have since updated the file, retaining the same name and guest link. The link has stayed in the exact same, 'old,' format and did not convert to the 'new' format. I am wondering that now that sharepoint has seemed to change the algorithm to the guest link format, updating files in the 'old' guest link format is creating this issue.

Can anyone please shed some light on my issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Office 365 Enterprise E3 product license?
My environment's product license is Office 365 Enterprise E3. I have done a test in my SharePoint online and enable Allow sharing to authenticated external users and using anonymous access from Admin center.

The guest link like the following and it can be accessed successfully: 
https://SharePointsite/sites/teamLisa/_layouts/15/guestaccess.aspx?docid=09999eccf037243c994bc835bd5a49b85&authkey=ATVAdQHKlKUM06jcSqt10es

Turn external sharing on or off for SharePoint Online for your reference:

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Turn-external-sharing-on-or-off-for-SharePoint-Online-6288296a-b6b7-4ea4-b4ed-c297bf833e30